# How to create a table based on another 2 Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have two tables, imagine:

- Table 1:

  ```
  +------+
  | Name |
  +------+
  | John |
  | Mary |
  | Pete |
  +------+
  ```
- Table 2:

  ```
  +--------+
  |  City  |
  +--------+
  | Paris  |
  | London |
  +--------+
  ```

And I want a third table that has all the cases between these two tables:

```
+--------+---------+
|  City  |   Name  |
+--------+---------+
| Paris  |  John   |
| Paris  |  Mary   |
| Paris  |  Peter  |
| London |  John   |
| London |  Mary   |
| London |  Peter  |
+--------+---------+
```

Is it possible to do this? I can't do it with a join because they aren't related in any way.

Comment: use `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: Read up on cross join

Comment: Once you've looked up `CROSS JOIN` give it a try; if you fail then post your attempt(s).

Comment: Read about [CROSS JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/cross-join)

Answer (score 1):

> I can't do it with a join because they aren't related in any way.

You actually could do this with a `join`:

```
select c.city, n.name
from table2 c join
     table1 n
     on 1 = 1;
```

The condition in the `on` clause can be almost anything.

However, Cartesian products -- what you want to do -- are the basis for understanding joins.  So, SQL supports them directly:

```
select c.city, n.name
into table3
from table2 c cross join
     table1 n;
```

Actually writing this as an explicit `join` is not as crazy as it sounds.  If either table is empty, then the `cross join` returns no rows.  Sometimes, you want to keep rows in the other table.  Outer joins solve this problem:

```
select c.city, n.name
into table3
from table2 c full join
     table1 n
     on 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create third table then

Use this:

```
  Select * into Table3 from ( select City, Name from Name cross join City  ) as Tab

  GO
```

Else you may create a `view` for same.

```
 Create View NameCity 
 As
 select City, Name from Name cross join City

 GO
```

Comment: He asked for a table though, not a view. If the data needs to manipulated in any way later on, that wont work if creating a view because it doesnt have the same functionality as a table.

Comment: @Julia: I gave both options, creating a `table` has our advantage while creating a `view` has our. Depends on the use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Please use below SQL QUERY.

**This is SQL:**

```
create table table3 AS
select table1.Name,table2.City from table1 
join table2;
```

I hope using the above SQL your problem will be resolved.